# Retrieve a single value only

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

If you want to retrieve some value from a database you always has to use a class that shall contain a lot of data.

In my case, I want to retrieve one value only from a stored procedure and do I really need to use a class that shall contain a single value only?
How should I create inside of the .hbm.xml and how should I write in c# code when I dont want to use a class?

It is not a IList<> or similiar. A single value only that is string.

I'am still not enable to find a solution to this context.

The code below is used when you need to have class that shall contain alot of data.

```
sp_retrieveAllProductList.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="data_layer" namespace="data_layer">
  <sql-query name="sp_retrieveAllProductList">
    <return-scalar column="Produkt" type="string" />
    <return-scalar column="Produkt_kategori" type="string" />
    <return-scalar column="btn_namn" type="string" />
    exec sp_retrieveAllProductList :Produkt_kategori
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>



        public IList<Product4> RetrieveAllProductWithPriceNameAndBtn()
        {
            return _session.GetNamedQuery("sp_retrieveAllProductList2")
                            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Product4)))
                            .List<Product4>();     
        }



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace data_layer
{
    public class Product4
    {
        public virtual string PK_produkt { get; set; }
        public virtual string Produkt { get; set; }
        public virtual string Produkt_kostnad { get; set; }
        public virtual string btn_namn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say one value you mean like a string or int

Comment: In this context it should be "string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use `.UniqueResult`:

```
string value = session.GetNamedQuery("Named_Query").UniqueResult<string>();
```

You *should* be able to keep your mapping file pretty simple:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="data_layer" namespace="data_layer">
  <sql-query name="sp_single_value">
    exec sp_single_value :my_param
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: How about the hbm.xml file? How should the  return-scalar be written?

Comment: @FullMetalGame: Updated-- this is untested, but I think it should work